# How can I translate characters in a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have two strings:

`my($normal_alphabet) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';`

`my($crazy_alphabet) = 'qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm';`

I also have a string which is a sentence:

`my($sentence) = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'`

I need to translate the sentence using the two strings provided above. Essentially every occurance of a letter in `$normal_alphabet` should be replaced with its matching character in `$crazy_alphabet`.

a --> q

b --> w

and so on.

In `PHP` there is a function called `strtr` which does this handily.

Is there a PERL equivalent to this, and if not, how can I translate the string?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html) to translate characters:

```
my $sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';

$sentence =~ tr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
               {qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm};

print $sentence, "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Tit dxoel wsgvh ygb pxjftr gcts zit kqmn rgu.
```